# Zooming in JFreeChart using scrollbar (see google finance)

Tags: java, jfreechart, zooming, google-finance

Is it possible to have some kind of zooming functionality in JFreechart like it is in google finance? I know there is a zoom in and zoom out, but I would like to have the bar on the bottom with which you can specify your zoom level more precisely.

Anyone has a plugin/addon?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

[http://www.kode...](http://www.koders.com/java/fid650FB550DD23B6FA7BD7362B62D4B1C7B13A8890.aspx)

This example performs zoom on Mouse scrolling, so you may need to extend it by adding JProgessBar functionality.

Comment: Sorry I meant JSlider not JProgessBar